# Почему не парсится JSON с внешнего ресурса?

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Учусь парсить Json. Работаю в Android Studio.

[Пример из сети](http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/#comment-688) у меня  не дает результат (не выводит строку json) ни в Генимошен, ни на смартфоне. Интернет настроен. В проекте ошибок нет.

В логе вместо ожидаемой строки json получаю:

> my_log﹕ [ 12-13 11:33:06.493 13389:13389 W/System.err ] org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Вопрос: почему может выводиться данная ошибка?

Comment: Вы бы привели исходный json + ваш код - было бы намного лучше

Comment: Ошибка означает, что строка в `new JSONObject(strJson)` - пустая. В примере по ссылке эта ситуация может возникнуть из-за ошибки при скачивании файла (напр. если в ссылке ошибка). В этом случае, в логе до той строки, которую вы процитировали, должна быть еще одна ошибка.

Comment: но ее там нет...